# Child task canceled, Parent completed?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the .net Tasks, when children is attached.

I have the following test code:

```
void Test()
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    Task child = null;
    var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }, token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }, token);

    Thread.Sleep(500);

    Debug.WriteLine("State of parent before cancel is {0}", parent.Status);
    Debug.WriteLine("State of child before cancel is {0}", child.Status);

    tokenSource.Cancel();
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    Debug.WriteLine("State of parent is {0}", parent.Status);
    Debug.WriteLine("State of child is {0}", child.Status);
}
```

Result of this is:

```
State of parent before cancel is WaitingForChildrenToComplete
State of child before cancel is Running
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
State of parent is RanToCompletion
State of child is Canceled
```

Aparrently the parent task state is not `Canceled`, even though 
both tasks share the token, and child is attached.

How do i make the parent task return state `Canceled` when a cancellation occurs?

**NOTE**
If i throw an exception both tasks return `Faulted`.

Comment: It's `Faulted` that's the special state here where (for whatever reason) the childs' state is reflected in the parent. `Cancelled` is specifically [called out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/08/30/9889070.aspx) as "To end in the Canceled state, a Task must either have cancellation requested prior to starting execution, or it must acknowledge a cancellation request during its execution." and neither of those applies to the parent.

Comment: So parent task should wait for child task, and throw it's own `OperationCanceledException` for its state to be cancelled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior as stated on MSDN. The parent task has to [wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997417(v=vs.100).aspx) (scroll down to the cancellation section) for the child task. The parent task has to handle all benign faults (like cancellation).

To make your parent task fail, just wait and pass the token:

```
Task child = null;
var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) Thread.Sleep(100);
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }, token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default);

  // This is the magic line.
  child.Wait(token);
}, token);
```

If you are using this code to do something productive and not only for testing, you should also consider using the simplified `Task.Run()` which supports `async` delegates instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. This [article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) is very interesting.

Comment: Where it is documented that this is the expected behavior? I can't find it.

Comment: See the link to MSDN I added in my answer.

Comment: I read that link, Can't find it still. It says that you have to wait for the parent task to handle the exception not the child task as you say in your answer. Can you quote the exact text which means it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It does not say to wait *for* the parent task, but *on*: "It is very important to wait *on* the parent"

Comment: Forget about it. It doesn't matter. Where did you read you have to wait for child task? I can't find it. It looks like docs doesn't calls this out.

Comment: My code is used in production. I sync some data from a SQL DB, so I spawn tasks to fetch data, with `ContinueWith`, when data is fetched and can be analyzed. I thought it was implicit that parent would cancel if token was canceled and parent was waiting, but obviously not. Thank you for the assistance. I obviously misunderstood what the expected behavior was. Everything is running smoothly now.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: it's under the section _When a Child Task Cancels_ in the article.

Comment: @Nautious Even though it is working now I highly recommend you switch over to `Task.Run()` and use `async/await` instead. See the linked article. You don't loose anything and can only win.

Comment: I can't use `Task.Run()` since it adds `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach`. I use async/await when possible.

Comment: Why do you need to attach to parent (I'm curious)?

Comment: Well, since I now manually wait for child tasks to complete, and the `Wait.All` rethrows child exceptions, then I do not need to attach children any more. Cancellation and Faults still behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is quite convoluted and hides the intuitive behavior and your expectations are wrong.

Let's start from the working example:

```
void Test()
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    Task child = null;
    var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }, token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default);

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }, token);

    Thread.Sleep(500);

    Debug.WriteLine("State of parent before cancel is {0}", parent.Status);
    Debug.WriteLine("State of child before cancel is {0}", child.Status);

    tokenSource.Cancel();
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    Debug.WriteLine("State of parent is {0}", parent.Status);
    Debug.WriteLine("State of child is {0}", child.Status);
}
```

In order for the parent to be canceled, you need to call somewhere in the body of the parent `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. However, just calling `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` won't suffice.

You need to conceptualize how `parent` and `child` execution flows go together in order to see why your expectations are wrong.

```
Main thread: ---\------------------------------------[Cancel]-----/
Parent:          \---\-----[Check cancellation]------------------/
Child:                \------------------------------[Cancel]---/
```

As you can see from the diagram above, the parent checks for cancellation way before the cancellation is requested. The child receives the cancellation signal because it basically waits for a cancellation to be triggered. Now, if you put the same mechanism in the parent it will receive the cancellation signal because it wouldn't have finished it's job prior to the cancellation being signaled.

Answer (score 0):

When an attached child task cancels

The  [standard version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks#when-an-attached-child-task-cancels) of the documentation states that you need to wait FOR the parent task.

When I've tried to wait for parentTask.Wait() in the main thread - no error.

The [old one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd997417(v=vs.100)#when-a-child-task-cancels) 'wait ON the parent task'.

When I've tried to wait for childTask.Wait() in the parentTask and then wait for parentTask.Wait() in the main thread - I've got an error.

So the current documentation misleads.
On the other hand, a parent task should wait for all attached child tasks by default. So I don't understand why I should explicitly wait for childTask.Wait() in parentTask to catch TaskCanceledException in the main thread.